# onClick listener for dynamic view in Listview inside Fragment

Tags: android, button, onclick, listener, fragment

I have the following button-in-Fragment problem:

My custom adapter throws out a row in my listview. That row has a (remove) button.
When the user clicks on the button in the row, the row is removed (and he button as well, duh). I have this working perfectly in an activity. But, how does this work in a Fragment?

If I use findViewbyId in onCreateView it crashes, because the view simply does not exist yet.
onClick in xml is also not an option, that does not work for fragments.

Somewhere I should be able to place a onClick listener and be able to remove it with adapter.remove. But where to place it and what does it look like?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're saying correctly you should add the `onCLickListener` to the button from within your adapter.

Comment: This helped me out. I added the onClickListener in my custom ArrayAdapter. I added a toast, and found out clicking on the remove button worked. However, the real deletion of the row takes place in an activity-method. For that to work out, I used a callback and interface, guided by [this stackoverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14822902/how-to-call-main-activitys-function-from-custom-arrayadapter)

Answer (score 0):

Use onViewCreated() ..it is called after onCreateView, when the view returned has been added.