# How to pass data from adapter to fragment in android studio

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-adapter, baseadapter

String value i.e. `accountname` is not passed to fragment.

In Adapter Class

```
Dashboard fragobj = new Dashboard();
bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("accountname", accountName);
// set Fragment class Arguments
 fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
```

In Fragment

```
lvDashboard = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvDashboard);

if (getArguments()!= null) {
   accountname = getArguments().getString("accountname");
}

tasks = new ArrayList<String>();
tasks.add(tasks.size(),accountname);
lvDashboard.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,tasks));
```

It looks fine, but string value is not stored in `accountname` variable in fragment.

Comment: what's the problem in current code?

Comment: it looks fine but satring value is not stored in acountname variable in fragment

Comment: Are you using that fragment instance?

Comment: yeah m using fragment instance

Comment: use `fragobj` object for fragment initialization

Comment: You can use an interface to communicate between the adapter and the fragment

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14822902/how-to-call-main-activitys-function-from-custom-arrayadapter  .Write interface and use as the callback

Comment: ok thanks Ahlem and rupesh

Comment: Just pass the instance of fragment in the constructor of the adapter and call the method from that instance

Answer (score 0):

You can use Listener/Callback in your custom Adapter something like this:

```
public class NameAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
  ...

  private AdapterListener mListener;

  // define listener
  public interface AdapterListener {
    void onClick(String name);
  }

  // set the listener. Must be called from the fragment
  public void setListener(AdapterListener listener) {
    this.mListener = listener;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // view initialization
    ...

   // here sample for button
   btButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
              // get the name based on the position and tell the fragment via listener
              mListener.onClick(getItem(position));
            }
        });

       return convertView;
   }
}
```

Then set the listener in your fragment:

```
lvDashboard = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvDashboard);
lvDashboard.setAdapter(yourCustomAdapter);
yourCustomAdapter.setListener(new YourCustomAdapter.AdapterListener() {
    public void onClick(String name) {
      // do something with the string here.

    }
});
```

---

Or, you can use [setOnItemClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener(android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener)) from the ListView:

```
lvDashboard.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
      String name = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
      // do something with the string here.
    }
 });
```